# Simulating accelerometer in proteus

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, simulation, accelerometer, proteus

I am not able to find any libraries for simulating accelerometer in **proteus**. Is there such a library? If NO, how do i simulate an embedded system that has an accelerometer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, There is no accelerometer library for proteus and there is no way to simulate it also.

But if you are just trying to check if your code is working before an an actual implementation, you can do that by just taking 3 'Torch LDRs' (a controllable library for LDRs in proteus), One acting  and connect them to a microcontroller's ADC and simulate it. This will just give you an idea if your codes working or not and then you could try some real life implementation

Hope this solves your problem. If you have any other issues just comment!

Comment: Only problem with that is, the accelerometer that i am using is digital in nature (I2C communication). So I used a I2C based temperature sensor to validate the code and I could get the temperature but same code(making required changes like slave address etc) did not work for accelerometer. So I was wondering if it can be simulated.

Comment: could you post the code over here. I have worked with I2C before. Maybe I could help you figure out what the problem is.
Also check your connections and see if you're using proper pull up resistors as well. 
There also may be a chance that there are pull ups already integrated with the sensor, In that case adding external pull ups would just mess up the values.